# Can stepper motor drivers switch quickly between full and micro stepping?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am trying to turn something with a stepper motor very quickly, but have it end up in a very precise spot. I would like to use full stepping to get a lot of torque so it can accelerate quickly, and when it gets close to where it needs to be, switch to microstepping so I can position it precisely.

What type of driver should I look into for this? How quickly can I switch between full and microstepping? Do I need to bring the motor to a complete stop before I switch?

Comment: Consider what you want your driver to do: if it's at some intermediate microstep position, what should it command next?   The next one or two coil position?  An intermediate position one full step away from the current one?   You can command the coils about as fast as your drivers and supply voltage can change the current; the question is what you would command them *to* and how that would fit with your acceleration profile.

Comment: When you are microstepping you can accelerate to a higher step frequency than you can use when single stepping. IMO you won't get to your target position any quicker single stepping, you just use less steps.

Comment: It is the lag angle and the level of current in the windings that determine the torque.  If you take a whole bunch of microsteps to start out, you'll accelerate just as fast as full stepping.  Best thing would be to stay with microstepping and work on your pulse timing.

Comment: Also, see my response to "Increase the ramp up stepper motor performance", on this forum.  There can be stability issues as high step rates!

Answer (score 0):

A stepper driver that I use a lot is the AMIS-30543, microstep and currently limit can be adjusted on the fly.
https://www.pololu.com/product/2970